# Calling the right controllers on routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

im having trouble in some situations, for example in my app, i have a cms table and a products table.

My routes are for example:

```
Route::get('{slug}', 'Frontend\ProductController@view')->name('frontend-view-product');
Route::get('staticpage', 'Frontend\SiteController@view')->name('frontend-view-static');
Route::get('{slug}', 'Frontend\CmsController@view')->name('frontend-view-cms');
```

The only problema is that the routes gets messed up, is there a way that i can maintain my current routes and make the routes being called in the correct controllers?

Answer (score 2):

maybe its because you user same routes in the first route and third route.. as far i know using bracket in route make it as variable.. try to make it different

```
Route::get('product/{slug}', 'Frontend\ProductController@view')->name('frontend-view-product');
```

`Route::get('cms/{slug}', 'Frontend\CmsController@view')->name('frontend-view-cms')`

Comment: I have ideia that i could do this way, but i dont want to go this path, this makes the url not very semantic in terms of seo, i need to be a unique slug.

Comment: then you can make it in one controller... just use one route in on controller and one function. check the value slug, and redirect it to different view..

Answer (score 0):

You already have answer, But you can try this option too. Hope it will work.

```
Route::get('{slug}', 'Frontend\ProductController@view')->name('frontend-view-product')->where('slug','prod');
Route::get('staticpage', 'Frontend\SiteController@view')->name('frontend-view-static');
Route::get('{slug}', 'Frontend\CmsController@view')->name('frontend-view-cms')->where('slug','cms');
```

`Where` will match slug parameter with `prod` and `cms` and it will call matching controller action.

Comment: This is what i pretend to do it, i wish to have a unique url

Comment: @CodeJam If you have unique url, laravel will always go with first one. It will not look for second route with same url. You need some condition to differentiate unique URL call.